# How to get AsyncTask Completed Status From Non Activity Class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to wait until my `AsynTask` is finished before continuing on.
The status always shows as **RUNNING** however.
How can the `AsyncTask` signal back that is has finished?
Why is my while loop endless? I thought that once `onPostExecute()` is called on the task
the status gets changed to FINISHED.

```
private void methodOne(Context context) {

MyNewTask getMyTask = null;

    try {


        getMyTask = new MyNewTask(context, null, null, param1);

        getMyTask.execute(getUrl());

        while(getResourceTask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)){

            Log.i("log", "STATUS : " + getMyTask.getStatus());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this method executed in UI thread? If so, `onPostExecute()` won't have a chance to be executed (UI thread blocked).

You normally don't wait for AsyncTask to complete by looping. This is a serious code smell.
You should just start whatever you want to do in `onPostExecute()`.

So, instead of

```
task.execute();
while(task.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)) {};
doSomeWork();
```

You should use:

```
task.execute();
```

And:

```
void onPostExecute(Param... params) {
    doSomeWork();
}
```

Where `doSomeWork()` is a method in class that calls `AsyncTask`. This way you get informed that task has finished.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, my AsyncTask is on a separate class of its own...it is not a subclass. how can i get it to signal back that it has finished to the calling class?

Comment: This has nothing to do with classes. It has to do with threads. If the while loop is run on main thread (not in another `AsyncTask` or `Thread`) it will block this main thread. `OnPostExecute` is always called in this main thread, so it will be blocked from running as well. I already posted how you should aproach this